# Make [oracle-service-bus] a synonym of [osb]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I think [oracle-service-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-service-bus) should be a synonym of [osb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osb) as they are both talking about the same thing. [osb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osb) has nearly 5 times as many questions (148 vs. 34) and a more substantial wiki. Noticed this while reviewing tag wiki edits, but don't have points in either to formally suggest a synonym.

Comment: The relationship should be reversed.  Acronyms are *bad* for discovery and clarity.